How do i add Binance payment for my app to accept crypto after being verified?
I signed up for the Binance merchant account and got verified. after generating the Api key when trying to test the payment using NodeJS I encountered many problem . does anyone have a full guide that shows where to get each keys like BinancePay-Certificate-SN and uses it on flutter?
{
  "env": {
    "terminalType": "APP"
  },
  "orderTags": {
    "ifProfitSharing": true
  },
  "merchantTradeNo": "9825382937292",
  "orderAmount": 25.17,
  "currency": "USDT",
  "goods": {
    "goodsType": "01",
    "goodsCategory": "D000",
    "referenceGoodsId": "7876763A3B",
    "goodsName": "Ice Cream",
    "goodsDetail": "Greentea ice cream cone"
  }
}

I got this error
